# Postgres - Partition pruning and query performance

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-11

I created a fact table with range partition on a date column and when a SQL statement is executed like this:

```
 Select * 
 from my_table 
 Where dt_col between to_date('01/01/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') 
                  and to_date('01/31/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

is taking more time but the same SQL with different format on the date filter (as below) is taking less than the above SQL

```
Select * 
from my_table
Where dt_col between date '01/01/2017' 
                 and date '01/31/2017'
```

and I do see some changes in the cost of the plan even though both SQLs hitting the same partition on the table. Can you explain what's wrong in the first SQL?.

When the same statement is executed thru' DBeaver or PG Admin it completes under 10 mins (returning 20+ Million records) but when it's being executed thru back end process using the JDBC (extracting the data from the table and writing to a file in the server) it's running for more than 2 hours and never completes (had to kill the process).

Any settings need to be changed in the database?.

Comment: I presume you're using a `PreparedStatement` in your Java code? If so, and you're on Postgres 12, try setting `plan_cache_mode` to `force_custom_plan`.

Comment: We are using version 11 . where do I set the plan_cache_mode?.

Comment: Try setting `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` and reload. Then you will get the actual SQL statement in the log. Please add that to the question, it will help determine what exactly is executed.

Comment: "_where do I set the `plan_cache_mode`_" -- in version 12

Comment: setting the setAutoCommit(false) and setFetchSize(10000) did the trick for extracting large volume of data in the backend java class.

Comment: just stumbled upon this by accident. It's not related to my actual question but it's really interesting and I wonder whether you ever managed to find an explanation, @Krishna?